# How do I put the brand, receiver name, and disconnect button for Chromecast into Android's lock screen?

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

Google states that I need to put the brand, receiver name, and a disconnect button on the lock screen.  I'm not sure how to do this since there aren't any fields in MediaMetadataRetriever for this data.  Currently I'm doing the following and all I get is the artwork, title, and controls.

```
remoteControlClient
    .editMetadata(true)
    .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "Title")
    .putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK, bitmap)
    .apply();
```

Since someone requested the surrounding code here's some of it:

```
private LockscreenManager(Context context) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    ComponentName myEventReceiver = new ComponentName(context, MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class);
    audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(myEventReceiver);
    if (remoteControlClient == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        intent.setComponent(myEventReceiver);
        remoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0));
        audioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(remoteControlClient);
    }
    remoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
    // android built-in lockscreen only supports play/pause/playpause/stop, previous, and next.
    remoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
            | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS
            | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT);
}    

public void setMetadata(Film film, Bitmap bitmap) {
    remoteControlClient
        .editMetadata(true)
        .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, film.getDirectorString())
        .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, film.getTitle())
        .putLong(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, film.getDuration()/60)
        .putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK, bitmap)
        .apply();
}

public void requestAudioFocus(Context context) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
            new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {}
            },
            // Use the music stream.
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            // Request permanent focus.
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
}

public void removeLockscreenControls() {
    remoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_STOPPED);
}

public void setLockscreenPaused() {
    remoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PAUSED);
}

public void setLockscreenPlaying() {
    remoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire RCC code? I need the same but can't get it work following RandomPlayer sample

Comment: One important piece that can be easily overlooked and would result in not seeing the lock screen is the audio focus; you need to request the audio focus otherwise you won't be able to see the lock screen. You need to include a line like: mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);

Comment: Is your lock screen work perfect as you want? I want to implement it for my Music app. Please let me know if it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information in the UX Guideline is unfortunately not accurate. RemoteControlClient currently doesn't support the "Stop" button (under strange circumstances you can make that visible like setting the state to Buffering but that is not what you want) so you can skip the "stop" button that would be the natural choice for the disconnect action. In terms of buttons, you can add only show play/pause, next and previous; the FF and REW don't show up. Finally, on Tablets (at least on Kitkat), the lock screen shows your app's icon but on phones it doesn't. So to summarize, you don't need to implement disconnect fro the lock screen, nor the branding (for phones).

Comment: Nexus 5 also shows app icon on lock screen, so not really only on tablets.

Comment: That is correct; in fact that is a KitKat feature across all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to generate a dynamic bitmap, considering the height and width of the device, and then set that bitmap to

putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK, bitmap)
        .apply();

In this bitmap you can have your brand name, app icon etc. etc.

I have used this technique to show a Pause button and at the background a very nice image at the lock of the screen.

Regards