# RemoteControlClient only shows play/pause toggle on lockscreen

Tags: android

I have a RemoteControlClient on my Android app and I gave it the following flags:

```
 myRemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_REWIND |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP);
```

However when it shows on the lock screen I only see pause or play depending on whether I am playing or paused.

Is there no way to show the other controls?

Thank you.

EDIT: here is the rest of my code:

```
    ComponentName myEventReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), PlayingBroadcastReceiver.class.getName());
    myAudioManager =
            (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    myAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(myEventReceiver);
    // build the PendingIntent for the remote control client
    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(myEventReceiver);
    PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
    // create and register the remote control client
    myRemoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);

    myRemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY |
                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE |
                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_REWIND | RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD |
                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP);
    myAudioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(myRemoteControlClient);


    myRemoteControlClient.editMetadata(true)
            .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, item.getTitle())

            .putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK, item.getBitmap())

            .apply();
    setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
    //Request audio focus for playback
    int result = myAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this,
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Comment: Without seeing all your code it's hard to tell, that code you pasted is exactly like the sample). Have you taken a look (and run) the Android Sample for MediaPlayer?

Comment: I do have the Random Music Player sample running and it only displays next and play/pause despite it also passing stop as one of the flags. And yes I pretty much just copied the sample.

Comment: I think this answers my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108935/how-do-i-put-the-brand-receiver-name-and-disconnect-button-for-chromecast-into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP never shows stop because of bug in android as reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29920

I'm not sure if it is the support lib (are you using it?) or not that causes the fast_forward and rewind to not work. 
I can't get them to show either so I'm using next and previous instead. I't might also be that they are not visible in the lockscreen but might be usable through headsets and other remote controlers that implement them.

Comment: Yeah the forward and rewind don't work either but previous and next do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE

`oRemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);`

And lie to the RemoteControlClient ;-)

Tell him the stream is buffering and it will show the stop button!

`oRemoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_BUFFERING);`

Cheers

Comment: "o" means "object". "oRemoteControlClient" is an instance of RemoteControlClient

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement to show icons

```
myRemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
                        RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY   |
                        RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE  |
                        RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS |
                        RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT );
```